# Local Network - Windows 7 and Vista can't see each other

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, networking

I've got a strange issue at home that has been bugging me for weeks, but I really need to get it sorted now so I'll detail as much as I can and hopefully someone can spot what might might be wrong.

I have a wireless router connected to the internet and 3 devices connected to it. They are:

```
Name    OS           Network     IPv4
PC1    Windows 7    WORKGROUP   192.168.2.2
LAPTOP1   Vista     WORKGROUP   192.168.2.3
PS3                             192.168.2.4
```

and they all get their IP addresses dynamically.

Both PC1 and LAPTOP1 can ping PS3 and get a response. PC1 and LAPTOP1 are unable to ping each other by ip address unless I ping by their name (which bizarrely shows that it is pinging via the IPv6 address). Also, to confirm this both PC1 and LAPTOP1 can ping each other via the long IPv6 address that they both have so they can obviously see each other just not via IPv4. I've disabled the firewalls on both machines as well to rule that out.

I don't really know what IPv6 is used for and I've tried disabling it on both machines but all that happens then is that neither machine can see each other at all then. Does anyone have any idea of what may be stopping them seeing each other, any ways I can look at fixing this, or any network tools that may help identify where it is failing?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I just want to verify that under "Network and Sharing Center" that "Network discovery" and "File sharing" are both On.

Answer (score 1):

Even with Network Discovery on for your Public, Domain, and Work or Home profiles, there are other services that it is dependent on. These services might be disabled or set to manual. Turn on these and try again:

Network discovery requires that the DNS Client, Function Discovery Resource Publication, SSDP Discovery, and UPnP Device Host services are started, that network discovery is allowed to communicate through Windows Firewall, and that other firewalls are not interfering with network discovery.

That is a quote from windows help "What is network discovery?". I got there by going to control panel > network and sharing center > advanced sharing settings > What is network discovery. Windows help actually...helped! It solved my issue between two win7 boxes because the Function Discovery Resource Publication was set to manual, but I'm not sure if it will help between win7 and vista. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Default gateway's IP address *(the router's ip address) ?
What subnet mask are you using for all three devices? try 255.255.255.224 for all devices
This limits the subnet to 16 valid IP addresses in your network. 
192.168.2.1  Default gateway (im assuming) | 192.168.2.2 | 192.168.2.3 |192.168.2.4 etc up to
192.168.2.15

Both computers need to be on the same type of 'network discovery' for example : Windows 7 is 'Home Network' and Vista is 'Priviate'

Comment: Yes, @Jaybee is on the right path I think... If you could open up the command prompt and run "ipconfig /all" for both PC's then give us the results.

Comment: Aren't there 30 hosts for your /27 mask instead of 16?